# Camera not working from downloaded play store ionic 4 android application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

ionic camera is working in local app when i publish the app in to play store. the camera functionality not working but photo library working fine. Even i install and added plugins of camera too.

Comment: Please check once you added permission for the camera on not.

Comment: yes added plz see this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />